# Laravel collection does not contains

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a larval collection and I am trying to get it to show results which do not contain a value.

I am aware of $data->contains(key, value), it basically needs to be the opposite of this. I am trying to do it within a blade template, with code like so;

```
    @if(!$orders->contains('order_status', 'Complete'))
```

and

```
    @if($orders->contains('order_status', 'Complete') === false)
```

but neither works as expected.

Any ideas or alternative approaches (want to try and keep the logic in blade if possible)?

thanks

---

var_dump of an item from the collection

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(26) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["cv"]=>
    int(0)
    ["cv_details"]=>
    NULL
    ["cl"]=>
    int(1)
    ["cl_details"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ja"]=>
    int(1)
    ["ja_details"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["order_status"]=>
    string(13) "PreAuthorized"
    ["advisor_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-18 10:38:06"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-18 10:38:22"
    ["preAuthId"]=>
    string(8) "29506753"
    ["days"]=>
    int(3)
    ["customer_value"]=>
    int(86)
    ["due"]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-21 10:38:22"
    ["ck_fee"]=>
    float(25.65)
    ["cv_company"]=>
    NULL
    ["cv_role"]=>
    NULL
    ["cl_company"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cl_role"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ja_company"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ja_role"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cv_sector"]=>
    string(2) "IT"
    ["cl_sector"]=>
    string(2) "IT"
    ["ja_sector"]=>
    string(2) "IT"
}
```

---

more code;

```
     @if($orders->contains('order_status', 'Complete'))
                    <h4>Completed orders</h4>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order #</th>
                            <th>Cost</th>
                            <th>Completed On</th>
                            <th>View Files</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($orders as $order)
                            @if($order->order_status == 'Complete')

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $order->id }}</td>
                                    <td>£ {{ $order->customer_value }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $order->updated_at }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="/view-order/{{ $order->id }}">View Files</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                @endif
                @if(!$orders->contains('order_status', 'Complete'))
                    <h4>Orders in progress</h4>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order #</th>
                            <th>Placed on</th>
                            <th>Due by</th>
                            <th>Cost</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($orders as $order)
                            @if($order->order_status !== 'Complete')
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $order->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $order->created_at }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $order->due }}</td>
                                    <td>£ {{ $order->customer_value }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $order->order_status }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                @endif
```

Comment: What does your collection look like? That's key to answering this question correctly due to how `contains` works.

Comment: @Samsquanch how can I post the collection without it being massive? is var_dump ok?

Comment: `var_dump($collection->toArray())` output with it just a few items.

Comment: Well, based on your collection, either way you're using the `contains` method should work. What do you get if you `var_dump($orders->contains('order_status', 'Complete'));`? Or some other status that is definitely in your collection?

Comment: so this is the weird thing, it shows true/false as expected. Ill post more code as the error must be with that, but I can't see it! thanks for help, good to know I was on the right track at least..!

Comment: Probably so. @mention me once you have more code posted and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Samsquanch I've added the template code. so the first table displays as expected, the second simply does not display. Other weird thing is if I get rid of the exclamation then it displays like the first table. And yes, there is a 'Complete' and then another item in the collection which has a status which is not 'Complete'. :D thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149525/discussion-between-samsquanch-and-ashley-prescott).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was just a logic error [as discussed in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149525/discussion-between-samsquanch-and-ashley-prescott).

```
@if(!$orders->contains('order_status', 'Complete'))
```

This is saying to only display the table when where are no orders with the `order_status` 'Complete' instead of the intended "show this if there are any orders that are not 'Complete'".

Answer (score 3):

I would add something to avoid the `!` to make it prettier:

`@unless($orders->contains('order_status', 'Complete'))`

Comment: This would be my preference, too. The less negation operators in your codebase, the better :)